# How can we know how many times a number is divisible by 2?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

For example 36:

36/2=18

18/2=9

So for 36 it is divisible by 2 2 times.

For 2ⁿ×(2k-1) it is divisible by 2 n times.

But how do I know for 3k-2?

Is there a formula to find how many times a number is divisible by 2?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. As far as I know this question is usually settled by trial division. The effort to do this for a given  $x$ is no more than $\log_2 x$. However, if the number is already represented in binary form, this is simply the number of trailing zeroes.

Comment: Take the last n digits if divisible by 2 raised to n so is the number. Works in any even base.

Comment: Are you asking about $3k-2$ specifically? There is a pattern in that $3k-2$ is divisible by $2^n$ but not $2^{n+1}$ if $k \equiv \frac{2^n+2}{3} \pmod{2^{n+1}}$ if $n$ is even, and if $k \equiv \frac{5\cdot2^n+2}{3} \pmod {2^{n+1}}$ if $n$ is odd. But I don't know of a way to just look at $k$ and identify the maximum $n$ without going through the equivalences.

Answer (score 2):

For $k = 1,2,3,\ldots$ and so $3k-2 = 1,4,7,\ldots$, the highest power of $2$ dividing $3k-2$ are:

$$1,4,1,2,1,16,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,8,1,\underbrace2_{k=16},\ldots$$

This looks like some translated or transformed version of the highest power of $2$ dividing $k$ (https://oeis.org/A006519), but instead term $4^n=2^{2n}$ first appears earlier than $4^n/2 = 2^{2n-1}$.

---

If $3k-2$ is divisible by up to $2^n$ (but not higher), then

$$3k-2 \equiv 2^n \pmod{2^{n+1}}$$

One form of $3^{-1} \pmod{2^{n+1}}$ is

$$\begin{align*}
3^{-1} &\equiv 1-2+2^2-\cdots + (-2)^n \pmod{2^{n+1}}\\
3\left[1-2+2^2-\cdots + (-2)^n\right] &= 3\cdot\frac{1-(-2)^{n+1} }{1-(-2)}\\
&= 1-(-2)^{n+1}\\
&\equiv 1
\end{align*}$$

Back to the mod equation,

$$\begin{align*}
3k-2&\equiv 2^n \pmod{2^{n+1}}\\
k&\equiv 2^n\left[1-2+2^2-\cdots + (-2)^n\right]+2\left[1-2+2^2-\cdots + (-2)^n\right]\\
&\equiv 2^n + \underbrace{\left[2-2^2+2^3-\cdots-(-2)^{n-1} -(-2)^n\right]}_{n\text{ terms}}\\
&\equiv \begin{cases}
2^n+0\equiv 1&& n=0\\
2 - 2^2+2^3 - \cdots -(-2)^{n-1} && n\ge 1
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$

From this form of $k$, if $n\ge 2$, $k$ is divisible by $2$ but not by $4$. Writing $k$ explicitly for some small $n$s, i.e. if $2^n\mid (3k+1)$ but $2^{n+1}\not\mid (3k+1)$,

$$\begin{align*}
n&=0, &k&\equiv 1 \pmod 2\\
n&=1, &k&\equiv 0 \pmod 4\\
n&=2, &k&\equiv 2 \pmod 8\\
n&=3, &k&\equiv -2\equiv 14 \pmod{16}\\
n&=4, &k&\equiv 6 \pmod{32}\\
n&=5, &k&\equiv -10\equiv54 \pmod{64}
\end{align*}$$

So if the divisibility of $k$ by powers of $2$ is known, without performing further division,

- If $1\mid k$ but $2\not \mid k$, then $1\mid (3k-2)$ but $2\not\mid (3k-2)$;
- If $2\mid k$ but $4\not\mid k$, then $4\mid (3k-2)$, but no further conclusions for higher powers of $2$;
- If $4\mid k$ (and possibly by higher powers of $2$), then $2\mid (3k-2)$ but $4\not\mid(3k-2)$.

Comment: That's right—see my comment to the OP above.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a simple formula of the kind you are looking for. Instead there is a gateway to some new ideas which have proved to be mathematically fruitful.

The Chinese Remainder Theorem guarantees that there is a number of the form $3k-2$ which is divisible by $2^n$ for any selected $n$. The Chinese Remainder Theorem is a whole lot more general than this, of course, and certainly isn't restricted to the prime $3$ the constant $-2$ or the prime $2$ - it will apply to a wide range of cases of which you state only an example. Cases like $4k-2$ are trivially rather different.

The intuition that this might be a useful thing to think about gets quite deep quite quickly - we have valuations and also the process of localisation - both of which look to keep track of what is happening with a particular prime: in your case $2$.

So the valuation might just be the power to which $2$ appears in the factorisation (though a related value is often taken). And one of the points about a valuation is that you can bound the distance between two numbers - this amounts to saying something about the power of $2$ which divides their difference.

Foundations such as Ostrowski's Theorem and Hensel's Lemma give rise to techniques which have proved to be mathematically fruitful. And at root they come back to the question "what power of $2$ divides $m$?" which you started with.